# Data Tables: How to display json data in datatables rows?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have following json response from server:

```
    {
    "rData": {
        "total": 17,
        "per_page": 3,
        "current_page": 1,
        "last_page": 6,
        "next_page_url": "http://localhost:9901/securityquestionlist/?page=2",
        "prev_page_url": null,
        "from": 1,
        "to": 3,
        "data": [
            {
                "question": "Accessor: 15th question",
                "full_name": "Dave Alex"
            },
            {
                "question": "Accessor: 14th question",
                "full_name": "Dave Alex"
            },
            {
                "question": "Accessor: 13th question",
                "full_name": "Dave Alex"
            }
        ]
    }
 }
```

I have following  HTML code:

```
 <table id="IdSQLTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
     <thead>
         <tr><th>Question</th></tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody></tbody>
 </table>
```

Following is javascript code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery('#IdSQLTable').DataTable({

            'ajax'  : {
                'url': 'http://localhost:9901/securityquestionlist',
                'data' :  function( d ){
                    d.myKey = 'MyValue';
                },
                'cache' : false,
                'method' : 'POST'
            },

            "columnDefs": [ {
                "targets": [ 0 ],
                "data": 'rData.data.question',
                "defaultContent": "Click to edit"
            } ]                
        });
    } );
```

I am unable to print 'question' in table. Can some one guide me how to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `ajax.dataSrc` to target `rData.data` :

```
ajax : {
  url: 'http://localhost:9901/securityquestionlist',
  dataSrc : function(json) {
     return json.rData.data;
  } 
  ...
}
```

and change the column definition accordingly :

```
"columnDefs": [ {
    "targets": [ 0 ],
    "data": 'question',
    "defaultContent": "Click to edit"
} ]
```

then it works -> **http://jsfiddle.net/cgzhdhos/**